# SQL Server on Ubuntu - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host after reboot

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, connectivity

I have been running SQL Server on Ubuntu for a while and everything has been working fine but I rebooted the server and now all connections to SQL Server fail with the error:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Server, setting various mssql-conf values (since removed again) etc. but nothing I do makes any difference.

Articles relating to Windows seem to point to it being SSL-related but SSL was not enabled. I did try to enable it and set a certificate but then even though I made permissions to the certificate and private key 777 and chowned to the mssql user/group it just told me it couldn't read it and then SQL Server failed to start up so I removed again.

Can anyone suggest anything I can do to get it working again please as I am out of ideas?

Thanks
Robin

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Sorry it's Ubuntu 19.04. I know it's not officially supported (only supported version is 16.04 for some reason) but it has worked well on 17, 18 and 19 since I started using it up to this week.

Comment: Although the install isn't blocked, there are known issues with SQL Server on later Ubuntu versions related to OpenSSL as described in this [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/installing-sql-server-2017-for-linux-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/). That's why it's not supported yet.

Comment: Up until now it has worked fine on each subsequent version and I have done workarounds in the past although it seems with the latest round of updates on 19.04 either this month or last month something is stopping it working. I just set up a new 19.04 Ubuntu instance and it does exactly the same thing which indicates something has changed recently in one of the packages that is affecting it. It's frustrating Microsoft only officially support a version 6 versions out of date.

Comment: Just set up a new VM using 18.04 and that fails with the same error and then I tried 16.04 and that one works so seems something has changed in some package recently in newer versions that has broken compatibility. 16.04 is too old for my other services so I will have to run an old legacy 16.04 instance just for SQL Server. It seems even the 2019 preview works on 16.04 too. Would appreciate it if anyone finds a workaround for this latest problem in the more recent versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: One workaround would be running a SQL Server Ubuntu 16.04 docker image on your later version host.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, I may try this but I have just finished setting up a new 16.04 VM and transferred all databases across and updated the config file of each .NET and SSIS project to not be localhost and re-published them all. At least switching in future will just be a case of updating the DNS (after server is built). I would have expected it to at least work on 18.04. As soon as things are out of date I am flagged for not meeting iso compliance so cannot run 16.04 generally as so old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSSQL expects OpenSSL v1.0 while Ubuntu 18+ uses OpenSSL 1.1, resulting in a [OpenSSL version mismatch. The solution](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Installing-SQL-Server-2017-for-Linux-on-Ubuntu-18-04-LTS/ba-p/385983) is to symlink ssl v1.0 as below:

1. Stop SQL Server

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
   ```
2. Open the editor for the service configuration

   ```
   sudo systemctl edit mssql-server
   ```
3. In the editor, add the following lines to the file and save it:

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mssql/lib"
   ```
4. Create symbolic links to OpenSSL 1.0 for SQL Server to use

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /opt/mssql/lib/libssl.so

   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /opt/mssql/lib/libcrypto.so
   ```
5. Start SQL Server

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mssql-server
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much @Dawoodjee that has fixed it and it now works again. I thought it was something SSL related but couldn't work out how to get it working again. Really wish Microsoft would officially support more recent versions.